# Rails assets are precompiled but production environment is looking for them in /assets

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am running a rails server in the production environment, and I precompiled my assets, but for some reason the requests are going to the /assets directory instead of /public.

I have the default production.rb file. What could be causing this?

```
# config/environments/production.rb

config.cache_classes = true
config.consider_all_requests_local       = false
config.action_controller.perform_caching = true
config.serve_static_assets = false
config.assets.compress = true
config.assets.compile = false
config.assets.digest = true
config.force_ssl = true
config.i18n.fallbacks = true
config.active_support.deprecation = :notify
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also change:

```
config.serve_static_assets = true
```

and then your assets will be served from /public/assets without having to use Apache or Nginx.

For development, just delete the /public/assets directory and then they will be automatically compiled and served from /assets.

Comment: quick solution I was looking for, but I urge people to look into Passenger (see below)

Answer (score 1):

Requests are going to `/assets`, which are served out of the `public` directory by the webserver which should sit in front of your Rails app.

Because you've got `config.serve_static_assets` set to `false` inside `config/environments/production.rb` there, Rails isn't going to even try to serve these assets.

I would recommend putting an Apache or Nginx server running [Passenger](http://www.modrails.com/) in front of Rails so that Apache or Nginx would serve the assets and proxy requests to your application.

Comment: I don't quite understand... I need 2 servers to make it work in production?

Comment: No... you need a server which sits in front of the Rails server and pipes the requests to it. Passenger will spool up an instance of your application automatically and deal with the piping of the requests. The frontend server (apache or nginx) is much faster at serving static assets than anything written in Ruby, that's why it's the preferred method.

Comment: Oh I dont really care if its fast, I just want the image to show up! The problem is its looking in the wrong folder for the images. Its in production but looking in assets/ instead of public/assets/

Comment: I'll give this Passenger server a try though. Im installing it now

Comment: It's looking in the correct folder :) `public` files are actually served without their `public` prefix. This is why you could put `index.html` inside your public dir, run `rails s` and go to localhost:3000 and see the contents of that `index` file locally, even though the request is `/`, and not `/public/`